# Angular2 - the whole view does not show up after the update

Tags: javascript, angular

I just updated my Angular2 app to the latest version, unfortunately a lot of things broke, now I am trying to solve issue by issue.
However, I am not able to figure out how to solve the below problem.
Before updating the below code was working fine, and now it stopped working for some reason, simply it does not show any error on the console. I perform a click, it does not show any kind of errors it stays on that same page!

Page1.html (I click here, nothing show, does not go to the next page)

```
<div (click)="goToFinalPage(category)" class="cards">
{{category.name}}
</div>
```

Page1.js

```
import {Http, URLSearchParams, Headers} from '@angular/http';
```

Page2.html

```
<div>Some content here</div>

<div *ngIf="itemsInCart()" class="footerCart" position="bottom">

</div>
```

I removed the below from **Page2** surprisingly it lets me move from page1 to page2:

```
 <div *ngIf="itemsInCart()" class="footerCart" position="bottom">

</div>
```

Page2.js

```
import {Pipe} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, URLSearchParams, Headers} from '@angular/http';


isEmpty() {
    return this.cart.items.length === 0;
  }

itemsInCart() {
    return !this.cart.isEmpty();
  }
```

Comment: can you post the complete code in files? It might be an issue with the imports too, its tough to figure out from those few lines of code.

Comment: The issue is that the files are large, and it very hard to copy everything and share it...

Comment: can you update your question with just the imports?

Comment: edited please check it out

Comment: thx for updating.. this code looks fine to me so far...  Try importing PipeTransformer and implementing PipeTransformer in your file2.js.